# DataTrigger, Binding to nested properties via TemplatedParent

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645024%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), it should be perfectly legal, and possible, to bind something to a nested property:

```
<Binding Path="propertyName.propertyName2" .../>
<Binding Path="propertyName.propertyName2.propertyName3" .../>
```

In my case, it's not so, though...

I have a custom control, `MyControl`, with a dependency property `ViewModel`:

```
    public static DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ViewModel", typeof(IViewModel), typeof(MyControl));

    public IViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (IViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
    }
```

and in the control template, I try to bind to properties in that viewmodel:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type my:MyControl}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type my:MyControl}">
         <Grid>
           <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=ViewModel.Text}"/>
           <Button x:Name="MyButton" Content="Visible by trigger" Visibility="Collapsed" />
         </Grid>
       <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=ViewModel.ButtonVisible}" Value="True">
           <Setter TargetName="MyButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
         </DataTrigger>            
      .../>
```

In the viewmodel itself, I have a preoperty Text as follow:

```
    public string Text
    {
        get { return m_text; }
        set
        {
            m_text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    public bool ButtonVisible
    {
      get { return m_buttonVisible; }
      set 
     { 
       m_buttonVisible = value; 
       OnPropertyChanged("ButtonVisible"); }
     }
```

I get no bind errors, but things doesn't happend...

Any clues?

**Edit**
It looks like the bindings work half way. When the text is changed in the editbox, my Text property is set, but if the Text-property is set in code, the ui won't update.

**Edit 2**
Looks like my first attempt at simplifying the case before posting was a little to successful... As @Erno points out, the code that I posted seems to work OK.

I have looked at the original code some more, and added a trigger to the scenario. The original code uses triggers to show parts of the ui at given conditions. These are also binded to nested properties. I now think that these triggers fail to trigger. I have updated the code. If it still doesn't show whats wrong, I can post a sample application some where.

Comment: Have you used a breakpoint to make sure the `OnPropertyChanged` is being raised correctly?  And do you get any Binding error messages in the output window?

Comment: The OnPropertyChanged-event is raised. If it is raised correctly or not, I don't know. How can I tell? 
There is no bindings error in the output window.

Comment: Can you use Snoop on your UI to see if there's a binding that's failing?  (The property will appear in red in Snoop if the binding is failing.)

Comment: For some reason, Snoop doesn't work on my machine. It wan't detect my application if started from VS. If started from explorer, Snoop detects the application, but wan't snoop it..

Comment: Do you run your VS elevated ("run as admin")?  If you do, then you also have to run Snoop as admin before it'll detect your apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a comma missing:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=ViewModel.Text}"/>
```

**EDIT**

Add Mode=TwoWay to the binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=ViewModel.Text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**EDIT2**

Got it! I could reproduce and fix it.

Replace the TemplatedParent with Self in the binding. 
[Read this explanation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a3bf91a8-e618-41c6-a1ad-be9e19581fd6/)

Comment: It would mess up the binding and that is the problem, isn't it? The code looks fine to me, are you sure you pasted the exact code you are using? Is the OnNotifyPropertyChanged of the ViewModel raising the correct info?

Comment: No, this is not the exact same code. It's a cleaned up, simplified case, and the missing comma was a typo. Visual Studio would notice if it was left out. My viewmodel implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and raises the Property Changed event with the name of my property, Text, as parameter.

Comment: I added an extra option to my answer

Comment: @Erno - the default binding mode for TextBox.Text is already TwoWay so specifying that in the Binding doesn't change anything.

Comment: @John/Erno: even a one-way binding wouldn't stop the UI updating when the property changed - a one-way binding doesn't write *back* to the property; it still reads.

Comment: It is just to hard to answer this question as the code is NOT containing the problem as far as I can see...

Comment: Maybe you're right, but posting thousand of lines of production code ain't an option, so I will always try to simplify and isolate before posting a question.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the same error in a new project without luck, so you may be right in that the error is not in the posted code. We use a couple of triggers to show/hide part of the ui, and these triggers depends upon some of the properties in the viewmodel. I know that the properties get changed, and that they invoke the property changed event, but for some reason the triggers wan't trigger...

Comment: I can reproduce the error in a separate project now. I have updated the code listings in the question with a datatrigger from my sample project. Sorry for waisting you time at first... :-/

Comment: @Vegar: Could it be that the interface IViewModel does not contain the Text and/or ButtonVisible properties?

Comment: In that case, I would expect a binding error in the output window. And the binding to Text property works, and if I bind the Visibility property directly against ButtonVisible property it also works. In my sample app, I have removed the IViewModel interface, and uses ViewModel class directly, but still no luck....

Comment: Wow! I'm impressed! It sure fixes my dummy application. Time will show if it also fixes the real code. Got to get some sleep first, though... Thanks!

Comment: I am still puzzled by the fact that there are no binding errors but templates are quite troublesome beasts... BTW: I'd never use a trigger for this, I'd use a converter.

Comment: I find binding quite troublesome where ever it is used... We have stumbled upon a new problem today :-/

Comment: Just wait for the next version (if it is similar to the next version of Silverlight) it will have Xaml-Binding debugging!